# Duration per task SPD Workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

When we start an approval process in a SPD workflow, we can fill in the "duration of the task" and/or the "due date ". But what exactly happens when we cross the date?

A reminder to the person with the task?
The workflow ends?
My laptop explodes? 
...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration per task can be specified in days, weeks, or months. When the unit time is "crossed", an action can be taken (e.g, the task escalated). Here is a detailed example showing a task escalation: [Task Escalation using Workflows.](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2008/10/task-escalation-using-workflows.html)